# Why is it possible to write integral if $\int_A f^+ d\mu$ or $\int_A f^- d\mu$ $< \infty$, but $\mu$-integrable requires both?

Tags: measure-theory

Why is it possible to write integral if $\int_A f^+ d\mu$ or $\int_A f^- d\mu$ $< \infty$, but for $f$ to be $\mu$-integrable requires both be finite?

That is,

Integral of $f$ over $A$ given either finite is:

$$=\int_A f^+ d\mu-\int_A f^- d\mu$$

But $f$ is $\mu$-integrable, that is, $f \in L^1(A;\mu)$, if both are finite.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @copper.hat Why is it enough for either to be finite for us to write the integral without it being $\mu$-integrable?

Comment: Because you already have defined the integral for non negative $f$.

Comment: One can arguable define the integral as long as **one** of them is finite, but to be in $L^1$ you need $\int |f|$ to be finite.

Comment: @copper.hat Ahh of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but here's an attempt:

It all comes down to $\infty-\infty$ not being well defined.

For a non-negative function $g$, $\int gd\mu=\infty$ makes sense.

However, if you have both $\int f^+d\mu=\infty=\int f^-d\mu$, then
$$
\int fd\mu =\int f^+d\mu-\int f^- d\mu=\infty-\infty
$$
and there's no meaningful way to assign a value to this.

Moreover, all the integration theorems (Dominated Convergence, etc) only work when the function in question is integrable